# Node.js Adding user to already existing google sheets

Tags: node.js, google-api

I want to make discord bot but I'm new to Google API but not new to Node.js. I can't seem to find any API reference for adding user through code with his email. Is there any documentation on it ? Or is that not possible ?

Example
!adduser hisEmail@gmail.com

and it would add him into the sheets.

Thanks for reading this and have a nice day!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `adding user through code with his email`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I wanna do a discord bot. Who would have command "!addloca xxx@gmail.com" and that would add the user email into the Google sheet so he can edit things. I can handle the discord coding part. But as I said I can't find any documentations for Node.js for this particular topic

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I wanna do a discord bot.`, I cannot find it in your question. So I recommend to update your question by adding more information of your goal and also your current script. By this, I think that it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to adding user email to specified Google files. You can try it

```
drive.permissions.create({
        **fileId**,
        requestBody: {
          emailAddress: **email**,
          **role**,
          type: "user",
        },
        sendNotificationEmail: false,
      });
```

fileId: 1QUp3xNP6kXIkeMFafiU_dWbPicIg4OPR6Nj.... (you can get it from API)

email: user email from your discord command

roles: specified permission. ex: owner, writer

You can check Drive API docs here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create?hl=vi

Comment: it gives me error "Error Login required". I have setupped command handler for discord maybe that's why or? Do you know any solution for this ?